# Large dataset of custom markers in Leaflet makes app very slow

Tags: leaflet, markers

I understand that there are many questions on leaflet performance issue but mine is slightly different. I want to render about 5k markers on a leaflet map. I already did it the regular way and I found it is way slower compared to Google Maps.

I'm looking for a way to render multiple markers without getting performance issues.

Is there a way to do this with Leaflet?

Update: I tried using circles and it is very fast as compare with a custom marker but I don't want to plot circles on the map. I want only custom markers on the map but it is very laggy.

Please suggest any way on that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clusters. https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#clusteringdecluttering

Comment: I know that but the answer which is accepted on that link is saying that to use circle but I don't want to use circles or cluster but I don't want to use any of that.

Comment: Is there any way to improve the performance of the map after adding the huge number of markers?

Comment: Yes; the way to improve performance are the things you just don't want to do. There's no [silver bullet](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/silver%20bullet). There's also https://github.com/eJuke/Leaflet.Canvas-Markers and https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.GLMarkers , but don't complaint that those don't work in the same way as HTML markers (re: interactive events).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195350/discussion-between-ragesh-pikalmunde-and-ivansanchez).